# Get Next Sibling gameobject(transform) Method in unity3d C#

Tags: unity-game-engine, nextsibling

looking a method or a Library for something like this:

```
GameObject nextBrotherNode= gameObject.transform.getNextSibling();
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You mean

```
int index = transform.GetSiblingIndex();
GameObject nextBrotherNode = transform.parent.GetChild(index + 1).gameObject;
```

Comment: not childs . just next object. at same level (next sibling)

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your request. Edited now.